# List rendering in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

How to i render a list with the answers:

```
<script>

export default {

data() {
return {

questions: {
question: "2+2 is...?",
answers: {a:'4', b:'6', c:'10'},
correct:'a'

}
}

}


}
</script>
```

i want to have `{{ questions['question`] }}`and`v-for` of answers;
in most of courses, they make a v-for but in way that they list all 'answers' of all 'questions' but not elements of object in one

Answer (score 0):

Inside that v-for, you can do another one to display the properties of your answers object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
<div v-for="answerKey in Object.keys(answers)">
  {{ answerKey }}: {{ answers[answerKey] }}
</div>
```

This will render answers like this:

a: 4
b: 6
c: 10

Comment: and what with :key?

Comment: @User5555 You can add `:key="answerKey"` if you want but it won't bring any benefits because answers is a "static" object in this example.